# Building a generator matrix

Tags: coding-theory

given $g(x) = (1+x)(1+x+x^3) \in F_2[x]$ as the generator polynomial of a binary (7,3)-code, I am trying to construct a generator matrix (of the form $(I_3|A)$ ) and parity check matrix. Below is my chain of thought:
Since $(1+x)(1+x+x^3) == 1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4$, but how do i choose $h(x)$? Is $h(x) = 1 + x^2 + x^3$ ok? What do i do after choosing $h(x)$? 
Is the matrix below a correct generator matrix for this case?

```
1 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 0 1
```

If yes, how can I get a the parity check matrix from this? if no, why not?

Comment: If the generator matrix is $\mathbf{G}= \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{I}_K & \mathbf{P}\end{bmatrix}$ then the parity check matrix is $\mathbf{H}=\begin{bmatrix}-\mathbf{P}^T & \mathbf{I}_{N-K}\end{bmatrix}$. In your case, $K=3$ and $N=7$.

Comment: Does that mean that my choice of $G$ is valid here? because I just chose $1 + x^2 + x^3$ with no formulation at all. You can say by mere intuition. Otherwise, how am I supposed to choose it? and how do i generate $G$ otherwise?

Comment: $h(x)g(x)$ should be $1+x^7$, because you want a cyclic code of length $7$. Verify it that this holds for your $h(x)$.

Comment: Do you know what $g(x)$ is as a _polynomial_ instead of the product of polynomials that you have shown? In general, the rows of the _systematic_ generator matrix are $g(x)$, $xg(x)\bmod g(x)$, $x^2g(x) \bmod g(x)$, $\cdots, x^{k-1}g(x)\bmod g(x)$ with coefficients of these polynomials being written in increasing order of degree: $1+x+ 0x^2+\cdots$ instead of in decreasing order of degree: $\cdots 0x^2+1x+1$.

Comment: @Dilip SarwateYes, $1 + x^2 + x^3$.  And after applying the the operations identical to the ones you have just described above and taking the results of the first $3$ and then permuting the columns, i get the matrix provided above. Is that right?

Comment: @Jyrki, thanks, i think I am getting closer to clearly understanding everything now :).

Comment: No, $g(x) = (x+1)(1+x+x^3)$ is a polynomial of degree $4$ and hence cannot equal $1+x^2+x^3$ which is of degree $3$.

Comment: oh, that is $h(x)$, $g(x)$ itself is already evaluated in the question above.